# Any way in Gulp to get matched glob pattern in stream?

Tags: gulp

Is there any way to know what glob pattern a Vinyl object in Gulp's `src()` stream matched? With for example the `rename` plugin, I can get the `Vinyl` object and get its `path`, `dirname`, and the like. But right now in my Gulpfile I have some logic to recreate the glob pattern via a lookup table (for syncing to a local live site from the dev repo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any documentation suggesting that the matched glob pattern is recorded alongside the file. If you pass an array into `gulp.src`, you can try and match the path of the current file to the array using the `micromatch` library. This would require the glob patterns passed in to be unique in that no more than one pattern could match a particular file.

An example to do this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    tap = require('gulp-tap'),
    mm = require('micromatch');

function example() {
    const srcGlobPatternsArray = ['src/js/**/*.js', 'src/css/**/*.css'];
    return gulp.src(srcGlobPatternsArray).pipe(
        tap((file) => {
            const globIndex = srcGlobPatternsArray.findIndex((element) => {
                return mm.isMatch(
                    file.history[0].substring(file.cwd.length + 1),
                    element
                );
            });
            if (globIndex !== -1) {
                console.log(
                    'Glob pattern matched: ' +
                        srcGlobPatternsArray[globIndex] +
                        ' at index ' +
                        globIndex
                );
            } else {
                console.log('Could not match glob');
            }
        })
    );
}

exports.default = example;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to accept this answer as "No: it's not possible directly to do so."